# circuit for quantum simulation?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, quantum-circuit, hamiltonian-simulation

What would be the circuit for operation exp(iθZ⊗Z⊗Z⊗X) by only using CNOTs and single-qubit gates. And How we can improve the circuit to implement the operation exp(iφZ⊗Z⊗X⊗Z ).exp(iθZ⊗Z⊗Z⊗X).Are there are multiple ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this circuit:
[image]
How did I come up with this? The shortcut is that I recognised the $Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes X$ as the stabilizer of a graph state, and that has certain standard rules for building it: apply a controlled-phase between the place of the $X$ and each of the $Z$ terms. In other words, if I group those three controlled-phase gates as "$U$", then
$$
U(Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes X)U^\dagger=I\otimes I\otimes I\otimes X,
$$
so
$$
Ue^{i\theta Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes X}U^\dagger=e^{i\theta X_4}=I\otimes I\otimes I\otimes R_X(2\theta)
$$
(depending on your convention for what the rotation matrix means.) Also, note that $U=U^\dagger$, so inversion is easy.

Now, you actually asked for controlled-nots instead of controlled-phases. We can convert between the two using Hadamards, and you have a fairly arbitrary choice of which qubit will be the target for each of the gates. A particularly efficient version is to make the bottom qubit the target every time.
[image]

If you didn't have that shortcut, how might you have gone about constructing this? My first reaction was to look at the $Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes X$, and apply Hadamard to the last qubit, so that you get $Z\otimes Z\otimes Z\otimes Z$. What does this observable detect? The parity of the number of 1s in a state. So, if you can find a circuit that computes the parity of the number of bits, you're effectively calculating the value of that observable onto a single qubit, so single qubit gates can add the phase that you need, and then you can uncompute the value. Controlled-nots are great at computing the parity of bit values.

As for your last question, for any Hamiltonian $H$,
$$
e^{i\theta H}e^{i\phi H}=e^{i(\theta+\phi)H}
$$
so instead of running your circuit twice, you only run it once, with an altered value of the phase rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Suzuki-trotter approximation to your Hamiltonian $e^{i\theta ZZZX}$ using two-qubit gates as mentioned in Qiskit's [operator-flow](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/operators/01_operator_flow.html#Evolutions,-exp_i(),-and-the-EvolvedOp) docs. Below is a sample code to perform the same ([Ref](https://qiskit-research.github.io/qiskit-research/tutorial_quantum_sim/qsim-tight-binding-model.html)).

```python
def compute_U_trot(H, time, trotter_steps, order=1):
    """
    Apply the Suzuki-Trotter approximation to the Hamiltonian H to 
    compute a trotterized unitary time evolution operator.

    """

    U_trot = Suzuki(trotter_steps, order=order).convert(time * H)
    return U_trot

def convert_U_trot_to_qc(U_trot):
    """
    Convert the U_trot ComposedOp object returned by compute_U_trot() 
    to a bare quantum circuit.
    """

    qc_trot = PauliTrotterEvolution().convert(U_trot)
    return (
        qc_trot.to_circuit().decompose().decompose()
    )  # add decompose methods so gates are not abstracted unitary blocks

H = PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(["ZZZX",],[1]))

time_param = Parameter("θ")
trotter_steps = 1

# Compute unitary time operator
U_trot_params = compute_U_trot(H, time_param, int(trotter_steps))

# Convert to trotterized unitary to circuit
qc_trot = convert_U_trot_to_qc(U_trot_params)
```

which gives the following circuit:
[image]

The other hamiltonians can be implemented in the same way.